# MySql The user specified as a definer ('mysql.infoschema'@'localhost') does not exist

Tags: mysql, centos, mysql-8.0, createuser

I tried to list all databases by running this command

`mysql> show databases;`

and got below error:-

> ERROR 1449 (HY000): The user specified as a definer ('mysql.infoschema'@'localhost') does not exist

then I tried to create user

`mysql> create user 'mysql.infoschema'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';`

got below error:-

> ERROR 1726 (HY000): Storage engine 'MyISAM' does not support system tables. [mysql.user]

to solve this issue I run `mysqld --upgrade=FORCE` but got error

> [ERROR] [MY-010123] [Server] Fatal error: Please read "Security" section of the manual to find out how to run mysqld as root!

then I run `mysqld --user=root` it worked . but no any output message

still I could not list all databases or connect the mysql server using dbeaver-cs tool.
All the sites are up and running without any issue.

mysql  Ver 8.0.26 for Linux on x86_64 (Source distribution)

OS- centos

Comment: Is this a fresh install or did you do a migration ?

Comment: I set up the fresh server and imported all databases from another server .

Comment: It worked before import all databases.

Comment: The problem might be in the `mysql` database. You should not take any of `information_schema, mysql,sys and performance_schema` databases when you backing up the db. If the users are important you can insert it. Take a dump of `users` table of `mysql` database from the older server. Then copy the insert statement form the dump, `use mysql` on the fresh server  database and insert it. If the fresh server is `MySQL 8+` and the older one is `5.xx` you will find missing columns just add it on the insert statement as empty columns

Comment: sure. I will try this and get back. Thanks

Comment: user table data already exists.  only root user is there.

Comment: Duplicate entry 'localhost-root' for key 'user.PRIMARY'

Comment: old server mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.4.18-MariaDB

Comment: Yeah i forgot to mention that you might have maybe 4 default users on the fresh server. Those users you should remove from the insert statement

Comment: I got mysql.infoschema user data from another server and tried to insert. I got error Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
so, can I drop user table and insert? is that effect anything?

Comment: I mentioned in the second comment that you will have missing columns check the difference between both versions :  https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5dQT5QB5Ytwmujuy7p9EfX/0  Last 6 columns you should add on the insert. can I drop user table and insert? is that effect anything? don't do this you will have the same problem .

Comment: Great. Its Working now :) you saved my life @ErgestBasha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually  the problem might be in the `mysql` database when doing a migration or backup.
You should not take any of `information_schema, mysql,sys and performance_schema` databases when you backing up the db.

If the users are important you can insert it.
Take a dump of `users` table of `mysql` database from the older server.

You will find maybe 4 default users on the fresh server,  those users you should remove from the insert statement.
Then copy the insert statement form the dump, `use mysql` on the fresh server database and insert it.

If the fresh server is MySQL 8+ and the older one is 5.xx you will find missing columns just add it on the insert statement as empty columns.
Last 6 columns you should add on the insert.

```
Mysql 8

mysql> desc user;
+--------------------------+-----------------------------------+------+-----+-----------------------+-------+
| Field                    | Type                              | Null | Key | Default               | Extra |
+--------------------------+-----------------------------------+------+-----+-----------------------+-------+
| Host                     | char(255)                         | NO   | PRI |                       |       |
| User                     | char(32)                          | NO   | PRI |                       |       |
| Select_priv              | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Insert_priv              | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Update_priv              | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Delete_priv              | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Create_priv              | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Drop_priv                | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Reload_priv              | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Shutdown_priv            | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Process_priv             | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| File_priv                | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Grant_priv               | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| References_priv          | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Index_priv               | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Alter_priv               | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Show_db_priv             | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Super_priv               | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Create_tmp_table_priv    | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Lock_tables_priv         | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Execute_priv             | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Repl_slave_priv          | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Repl_client_priv         | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Create_view_priv         | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Show_view_priv           | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Create_routine_priv      | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Alter_routine_priv       | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Create_user_priv         | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Event_priv               | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Trigger_priv             | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Create_tablespace_priv   | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| ssl_type                 | enum('','ANY','X509','SPECIFIED') | NO   |     |                       |       |
| ssl_cipher               | blob                              | NO   |     | NULL                  |       |
| x509_issuer              | blob                              | NO   |     | NULL                  |       |
| x509_subject             | blob                              | NO   |     | NULL                  |       |
| max_questions            | int unsigned                      | NO   |     | 0                     |       |
| max_updates              | int unsigned                      | NO   |     | 0                     |       |
| max_connections          | int unsigned                      | NO   |     | 0                     |       |
| max_user_connections     | int unsigned                      | NO   |     | 0                     |       |
| plugin                   | char(64)                          | NO   |     | caching_sha2_password |       |
| authentication_string    | text                              | YES  |     | NULL                  |       |
| password_expired         | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| password_last_changed    | timestamp                         | YES  |     | NULL                  |       |
| password_lifetime        | smallint unsigned                 | YES  |     | NULL                  |       |
| account_locked           | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Create_role_priv         | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Drop_role_priv           | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Password_reuse_history   | smallint unsigned                 | YES  |     | NULL                  |       |
| Password_reuse_time      | smallint unsigned                 | YES  |     | NULL                  |       |
| Password_require_current | enum('N','Y')                     | YES  |     | NULL                  |       |
| User_attributes          | json                              | YES  |     | NULL                  |       |
+--------------------------+-----------------------------------+------+-----+-----------------------+-------+




Mysql 5.7

mysql> desc user;
+------------------------+-----------------------------------+------+-----+-----------------------+-------+
| Field                  | Type                              | Null | Key | Default               | Extra |
+------------------------+-----------------------------------+------+-----+-----------------------+-------+
| Host                   | char(60)                          | NO   | PRI |                       |       |
| User                   | char(32)                          | NO   | PRI |                       |       |
| Select_priv            | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Insert_priv            | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Update_priv            | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Delete_priv            | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Create_priv            | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Drop_priv              | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Reload_priv            | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Shutdown_priv          | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Process_priv           | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| File_priv              | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Grant_priv             | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| References_priv        | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Index_priv             | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Alter_priv             | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Show_db_priv           | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Super_priv             | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Create_tmp_table_priv  | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Lock_tables_priv       | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Execute_priv           | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Repl_slave_priv        | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Repl_client_priv       | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Create_view_priv       | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Show_view_priv         | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Create_routine_priv    | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Alter_routine_priv     | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Create_user_priv       | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Event_priv             | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Trigger_priv           | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Create_tablespace_priv | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| ssl_type               | enum('','ANY','X509','SPECIFIED') | NO   |     |                       |       |
| ssl_cipher             | blob                              | NO   |     | NULL                  |       |
| x509_issuer            | blob                              | NO   |     | NULL                  |       |
| x509_subject           | blob                              | NO   |     | NULL                  |       |
| max_questions          | int(11) unsigned                  | NO   |     | 0                     |       |
| max_updates            | int(11) unsigned                  | NO   |     | 0                     |       |
| max_connections        | int(11) unsigned                  | NO   |     | 0                     |       |
| max_user_connections   | int(11) unsigned                  | NO   |     | 0                     |       |
| plugin                 | char(64)                          | NO   |     | mysql_native_password |       |
| authentication_string  | text                              | YES  |     | NULL                  |       |
| password_expired       | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| password_last_changed  | timestamp                         | YES  |     | NULL                  |       |
| password_lifetime      | smallint(5) unsigned              | YES  |     | NULL                  |       |
| account_locked         | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
+------------------------+-----------------------------------+------+-----+-----------------------+-------+
45 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: This was solved my issue. Thanks :)